# Unable to identify "Open" window form if run by agent on VM

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automation, autoit-c#-wrapper

My script should upload a file; clicks on the upload button and "Open" window form opens, then select the required file and click the "Open" button.

The AutoItX script is able to identify "Open" window form and take further actions if I manually execute the script on VM or locally, but when the script is run using agent (release pipeline) on VM then it is not able to and goes into infinite wait state.

Somehow the "Open" window is grayed when script is run through release pipeline (agent).
When the script is run by release agent on VM, the "Open" window pop up is not active after the script clicks on Upload button. What is the cause of this issue?

The script :

```
AutoItX.ControlFocus("Open", "", "Edit1");
Thread.Sleep(3000);
AutoItX.WinWaitActive("Open");
Thread.Sleep(4000);
AutoItX.ControlFocus("Open", "", "Edit1");
Thread.Sleep(4000);
AutoItX.ControlClick("Open", "", "Edit1");
Thread.Sleep(4000);
AutoItX.ControlSetText("Open", "", "Edit1", filePath);
Thread.Sleep(4000);
AutoItX.ControlClick("Open", "", "Button1");
```